# Removing special chars from words

Tags: string, go, unicode, trim

I was writing a function in GO for cleaning up individual words, in such a manner that special characters in the beginning and end of each would be removed.

ie:

- .-hello, -> hello
- "back-to-back" -> back-to-back

Ended up with the following, by checking letter by letter from each end if they belong to the unicode.Letter set, which works fine, but I was wondering if there are better or more efficient ways of doing so? I experimented with strings.TrimLeft/Right, but then I have to define my own set of chars to remove. It would have been nice to use a predefined set.

```
func TrimWord(word []rune) string {
    var prefix int = 0
    var suffix int = len(word)

    for x := 0; x < len(word); x++ {
        if !unicode.IsLetter(word[x]) {
            prefix++
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    for x := len(word) - 1; x >= 0; x-- {
        if suffix == prefix {
            break
        }
        if !unicode.IsLetter(word[x]) {
            suffix--
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return string(word[prefix:suffix])
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

func trimWord(s string) string {
    return strings.TrimFunc(s, func(r rune) bool {
        return !unicode.IsLetter(r)
    })
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(trimWord(`.-hello,`))       // -> hello
    fmt.Println(trimWord(`"back-to-back"`)) // -> back-to-back
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/l1A4hBDvFfr

```
hello
back-to-back
```

> [Package strings](https://pkg.go.dev/strings)
>
> ```
> func TrimFunc(s string, f func(rune) bool) string
> ```
>
> TrimFunc returns a slice of the string s with all leading and trailing Unicode code points c satisfying f(c) removed.

Answer (score 1):

In other word

You want first `unicode.letter` to last `unicode.letter`

You can get little improve if you don't care still using same way to get result

```
func TrimWord(word []rune) string {
    var prefix int = 0
    var suffix int = len(word)

    for ; prefix < suffix;prefix++{
        if unicode.IsLetter(word[prefix]) {
            break
        }
    }
    suffix--
    for ; suffix > prefix;suffix--{
        if unicode.IsLetter(word[suffix]) {
            break
        }
    }
    return string(word[prefix:suffix+1])
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Regular expressions are nice and concise.

`\pL` matches any Unicode letter; `\PL` is the same match negated (matches anything *except* a Unicode letter).

https://goplay.tools/snippet/SrezNxxawW7

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
  rx := regexp.MustCompile(`^\PL+|\PL+$`)
  input := "<'foobar'>"
  trimmed := rx.ReplaceAllString(input, "")

  fmt.Println(trimmed)
}
```